# Custom hosts file but with the possibility of replacing raw IP addresses

Tags: networking

I'd like to obtain the same behaviour as the hosts file does, but with RAW IP addresses.

Example; redirecting all traffic to 193.58.72.165 to 127.0.0.1

I've tried playing with bot netsh in Windows and iptables in Linux but both did not work. Is it possible that those aren't meant for this kind of redirecting?

A browser extension for this issue would also be totally appropriate, but I've only found hosts file equivalent extensions for now

Comment: `iptables` can do this on a *nix machine.  If you want to do this, do what I do - do it on a raspberry pi or similar for a whole subnet, etc and then instead of using the `hosts` file you can spoof DNS as needed for specific domains.

Comment: what command do you use for it? I remember doing it but nothing worked @ivanivan

Answer (score 1):

The `hosts` file is not a part of the **routing** configuration, but of the **name resolution** configuration. This implies, that for the OS to make a connection to a given IP address (a.o.t. a given hostname) the contents of `hosts` is not considered.

This also rules out a browser extension, as the browsers delegate name resolution and routing to the OS.

So for your problem on redirecting traffic IP-based you should look into something that works on the IP level, while I don't know if the normal Windows Firewall can do it, there might be other products that can even on Windows.

Comment: (1) “a.o.t.” = “as opposed to”?  (2) This seems like an unlikely browser extension — I don’t recall ever having heard of such a one — but how does anything you’ve said “rule out” a browser extension?  It’s a simple matter of programming: ```ip = resolve(hostname); ip = lookup(ip, translation_table);```.  It’s not really about routing.